# adding row automatically based on user input

Tags: java, swing, row

what i want to do is my table should automatically add row depends on the number of rows i input in a textbox. example if the user input 3 in the textbox and i click he clicked the jbutton the table will automatically have 3 rows with null values.. i'm just new to programming and this is a lab activity we did yesterday but no one seems did it

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table;
private JTextField textField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                WindowwwTry frame = new WindowwwTry();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public WindowwwTry() {
    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override

        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            table.setModel(dm);
            dm.addColumn("PROCESS");
            dm.addColumn("CPU Time");
            dm.addColumn("Arrival Time");
        }
    });
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setBounds(177, 123, 1, 1);
    contentPane.add(table);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(92, 24, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try{
            int ps = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());



            for(int x=0; x<ps; x++){
                dm.addRow(new Object[]{x});
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(206, 23, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
}
```

Comment: i got this code for the textfield action event

Comment: try{
    int ps = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
    
    
   
    for(int x=0; x<ps; x++){
     dm.addRow(new Object[]{x});
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. The problem you experience is that you don't see the results, because the size of your table is very, very small. Change the line where you set bounds to something like this:

```
    table.setBounds(177, 123, 200, 100);
```

Comment: yes it does, you can resize your window to see it, I changed the bounds to fit your window

Comment: how about i put 0 in the first row of the 2nd column and null values in the other how can i set 0 in the first row of 2nd column?

Comment: if i put 0 on dm.addRow(new Object[]{x,0}); it goes 0 on all the rows in 2nd column because of the forloop

Answer (score 0):

As @gawi said your table is too small (its width and height are 1 pixel). You should set it to some higher value (I tried using `table.setBounds(177, 123, 100, 100)` and it fits quite nicely in the window.

Also your for loop incorrect. You want that

> table will automatically have 3 rows **with null values**

so the for loop should look something like this

```
for(int x=0; x<ps; x++){
    dm.addRow(new Object[]{null, null, null});
}
```

to set to `null` all the 3 columns in your table